# Desanidar pares de clave valor en cadena de caracteres y convertirlos en columnas de un data.frame

Tags: r, nlp

Estoy haciendo NLP con la librería udpipe y la función de anotado de esta librería me regresa una data.frame con aproximadamente esta estructura

```
structure(list(word = c("cali", "con", "prohibición", "y", "todo", 
                        "con", "comunicado", "y", "todo", "en"), 
               upos = c("NOUN", "ADP","NOUN", "CCONJ", "PRON", "ADP", "VERB", "CCONJ", "PRON", "ADP"), 
               feats = c("Gender=Fem|Number=Sing", NA, "Gender=Fem|Number=Sing", NA, "Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Tot",
                         NA, "Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|VerbForm=Part",NA, "Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Tot", NA)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) -> corpus_anotado
```

Que se vé así:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
  word        upos  feats                                
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>                                
1 cali        NOUN  Gender=Fem|Number=Sing               
2 con         ADP   NA                                   
3 prohibición NOUN  Gender=Fem|Number=Sing               
4 y           CCONJ NA                                   
5 todo        PRON  Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Tot 
6 con         ADP   NA                                   
7 comunicado  VERB  Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|VerbForm=Part
8 y           CCONJ NA                                   
9 todo        PRON  Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|PronType=Tot 
10 en          ADP   NA
```

> Quité algunas columna que creo no son importantes.

El problema lo tengo en la columna `feat`. Quisiera utilizarla en el análisis para clasificar mejor mis palabras, el problema es que toda la información está en una cadena de caracteres separada por `|` y luego pares clave/valor separados por `=`.

Creo que una forma "tidy"  de manejar estos datos sería generar una columna por cada clave (Gender, Number, etc.) y ubicar el valor en cada fila, rellenado con `NA` cuando no aplique. Es decir, desanidar esa cadena de caracteres en k columnas, donde k es la cantidad de claves únicas en los pares.

Logré hacerlo con el siguiente código, pero busco ayuda porque el desempeño que obtengo es muy malo: mis corpus superan el millón de palabras y con la solución que encontré se muchísimo al punto de no hacer práctico el trabajo.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
library(tidyverse)
str_split(corpus_anotado$feats, "\\|") -> foo    # Esto es bastante rápido


ensanchar_feats <- function(x) {
  suppressWarnings(if(is.na(x)) {return(data.frame("sin_datos" = "sin_datos"))}) #is.na() rezonga pq las listas tienen length > 1
  as.data.frame(x) %>% 
    separate(names(.), c("key", "value"), sep = "=") %>% 
    spread(key, value)                                     #creo que este proceso es el lento
}

map_df(foo, ensanchar_feats)
```

Las preguntas:

- ¿hay una solución/aproximación óptima (o mejor) al problema de desanidar pares de clave valor en cadenas de caracteres y convertirlos en datos "anchos" en un data.frame?
- Si mi aproximación es razonable ¿Que parte del código que presento se podría cambiar para mejorar para aumentar el desempeño?

Gracias de antemano y quedo atento a los comentarios para mejorar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No sé que tan performante sea, además, que es una solución bastante similar a la que ya tienes, o al menos usa el mismo principio, salvo que todo se resuelve dentro de un único pipe:

```
corpus_anotado %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         KV = strsplit(as.character(feats), "\\|")) %>% 
  unnest(KV) %>% 
  separate(KV, into = c("K", "V"), "=") %>% 
  spread(K, V) %>% 
  select(-c(`<NA>`, 'feats', 'id'))

   <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   
 1 cali        NOUN  Fem    Sing   NA       NA      
 2 comunicado  VERB  Masc   Sing   NA       Part    
 3 con         ADP   NA     NA     NA       NA      
 4 con         ADP   NA     NA     NA       NA      
 5 en          ADP   NA     NA     NA       NA      
 6 prohibición NOUN  Fem    Sing   NA       NA      
 7 todo        PRON  Masc   Sing   Tot      NA      
 8 todo        PRON  Masc   Sing   Tot      NA      
 9 y           CCONJ NA     NA     NA       NA      
10 y           CCONJ NA     NA     NA       NA
```

Un mejora, podría ser aplicar esto solo en las filas dónde tengas un `feats`. Sino habría que ver algo directamente con R base o usar `data.table` que francamente no me he animado nunca a investigar.

Por el lado del uso del `unnest()` la idea salió de esta [muy buena respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33016191/6836377).

Comment: Por lo pronto es mucho más elegante y legible y eso será importante en unos mese cuando la vuelva usar. Informalmente no encontré mucha ventaja en performance, pero no hice benchmark apropiado. Originalmente evité usar `unnest` porque tiene problemas de performance documentados en https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/751. Ojalá le mejoren el desempeño, porque es una muy buena solución a datos anidados.

Comment: Lo que me llama la atención es que el desempeño baja mucho a medida que aumentan los datos. Usando tu solución para procesar 10000 filas el `system.time` es 3.484, para 129,351 filas el time fue 442.823.  Si fuera lineal debería haber estado alrededor de los 45. Con la solución que había estado usando tenía exactamente el mismo problema, para un data.set test pequeño era muy rápida, a medida que aumentaba el tamaño el tiempo crecía exponencial.

Comment: Muchas gracias de todos modos, tu solución mejora mucho la legibilidad del código y me ayuda a entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Que lástima lo de la performance, pero claramente un crecimiento exponencial para procesar filas es un comportamiento extraño, tal vez tenga que ver con realocaciones y copias de datos que internamente se hagan dentro del pipe. Te dejó otra solución más rústica pero creo que puede llegar a ser mejor.

Comment: En efecto, era con Rbase y data.table. Puse como respuesta la solución que le dio el desarrollador de `udpipe` (no había leído bien la documentación) que se podría considerar una solución general al problema de desanidar pares de clave valor en cadenas de caracteres. Me costaría mucho aprender data.table, porque tendría que desaprender muchas formas que encuentro obvias de solucionar problemas, pero que rápido que es.

Answer (score 1):

El problema tiene una solución específica en la misma librería `udpipe`: la función `cbind_morphological()` hace exactamente lo que necesito en tiempos muy cortos (~1.5 segundos para 130k filas).

[Aquí](https://rdrr.io/cran/udpipe/src/R/nlp_morphological.R) está el código de las dos funciones con las que el autor de `udpipe` soluciona el problema, la importante es `txt_morphological`, que no está exportada al `namespace` público de la librería.

Esta es la parte interesante y se la puede considerar una solución más o menos general y muy rápida al problema de separar un número arbitrario de pares de clave-valor en una cadena de caracteres. Dejo el código prácticamente como está, sin cambiar nombres ni envolver en una función.

```
x <- corpus_anotado$feats
morpho <- strsplit(x, split = "\\|") #lista de pares

morpho <- lapply(morpho, FUN=function(x) list(feats = x)) #nombra los elementos de la lista
morpho <- data.table::rbindlist(morpho, idcol = "id") #colapsa la lista a un dt

morpho$feats[is.na(morpho$feats)] <- "has_morph=FALSE"  #atiende a los NA
morpho$key <- gsub("^(.+)=(.+)$", "\\1", morpho$feats)  #esta y las dos que siguen hacen lo de separate
morpho$key <- tolower(morpho$key)
morpho$value <- gsub("^(.+)=(.+)$", "\\2", morpho$feats)

#la siguiente línea hace lo de spread pero MUCHO más rápido y produce un data.table del mismo largo que corpus_anotado, listo para cbind

morpho <- data.table::dcast.data.table(data = morpho, formula = id ~ key, value.var = "value")
```

## Conclusión:

- debería haber leído la @#~@#€¬€ documentación de la librería que estoy usando.
- había leído que `data.table` era más rápido que `dplyr` y flia, pero no esperaba que la diferencia pudiera llegar a 3 ordenes de magnitud.
- Qué maravilla es del código abierto: se aprende mucho viendo código escrito por otras personas.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra aproximación al problema, más rústica y tradicional. La idea es completar una matriz previamente allocada para alojar un numero predeterminado de keywords.

```
# Definimos la matriz, cada columna un keyword, cada fila
# es una fila del data.frame original
keywords <- c("Gender", "Number", "PronType", "VerbForm")
trows <- nrow(corpus_anotado)
m <- matrix(data=NA_character_, nrow=trows, ncol=length(keywords))
colnames(m) <- keywords

# iteramos por cada fila para extraer valores y completar matriz
for (i in 1:trows) {

  f <- corpus_anotado[i, "feats"]
  if (!is.na(f)) {
    KV <-strsplit(strsplit(f, '\\|')[[1]], '=')
    for (e in KV) {
      m[i, e[1]] <- e[2]  
    } 
  }
} 

library("tidyverse")
corpus_anotado %>% 
  bind_cols(as.data.frame(m))
```

Al menos, supongo que esta alternativa, no debería generar tiempos exponenciales a media que aumenta el volumen de datos. Nota: entiendo que los `keywords` es un dato que ya conoces, y deberías definir todos los que eventualmente podrían aparece ya que no estoy controlando la situación de `keywords` no definidos previamente.

Comment: En efecto, `udpipe_annotate()` produce un conjunto de `keywords` que podemos conocer de antemano y siempre serán los mismos (a menos que cambien la función). Creo que es buena pista y elimina el paso de `bind_rows()`, que es genial por funcionalidad, pero ineficiente en estge caso. Sigo testeando este código con los datos de producción, más complejos que los del ejemplo mínimo. Gracias!